# Need help parsing the data from the following Raw input in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
  "description": "NetSpy Integration",
  "event_type": "trigger",
  "service_key": "34a9a87f27f6173f",
  "details": {
    "uri": {
      "slashes": true,
      "search": "",
      "query": {
      },
      "protocol": "http:",
      "port": null,
      "pathname": "/integration/34a9a87f27f6173f /enqueue",
      "path": "/integration/34a9a87f27f6173f /enqueue",
      "href": "http://events.pagerduty.com/integration/34a9a87f27f6173f/enqueue",
      "hostname": "events.pagerduty.com",
      "host": "events.pagerduty.com",
      "hash": null,
      "auth": null
    },
    "rawBody": "{\"client_url\":\"http://GINC-prod-nsg-mon-5:9100/\",\"service_key\":\"34a9a87f27f6173f \",\"event_type\":\"trigger\",\"description\":\"Interface is down for a viptela router\",\"client\":\"NetSpyGlassTest\",\"details\":{\"client\":\"NSG\",\"client_url\":\"https://GINC.netspyglass.com/\",\"component\":\"ge0/1\",\"dedup_key\":\"$dedupKey\",\"device\":\"myrtr1\",\"event_action\":\"trigger\",\"payload.class\":\"deploy\",\"payload.cmdb_ci\":\"myrtr1\",\"payload.component\":\"postgres\",\"payload.custom_details.abc\":\"123\",\"payload.custom_details.def\":\"Hi, its Nikita\",\"payload.group\":\"prod-datapipe\",\"payload.severity\":\"{}\",\"payload.source\":\"https://GINC.netspyglass.com/\",\"payload.summary\":\"Interface is down for a router\",\"payload.timestamp\":\"\",\"routing_key\":\"34a9a87f27f6173f \",\"value\":\"2.0\"},\"incident_key\":\"ViptelaRouterInterfaceDown.9853.2\",\"contexts\":[{\"href\":\"http://GINC-prod-nsg-mon-5:9100/\",\"type\":\"link\"},{\"src\":\"https://GINC.netspyglass.com/emb_graph.html?update=true&networkId=1&intervalHr=24&width=500&height=300&vars=ifOperStatus.9853.2\",\"type\":\"image\"}]}",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": [
      {
        "X-Real-IP": "10.16.121.254"
      },
      {
        "X-Forwarded-For": "10.16.121.254"
      },
      {
        "Host": "events.pagerduty.com"
      },
      {
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
      },
      {
        "Connection": "close"
      },
      {
        "Content-Length": "1054"
      },
      {
        "User-Agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/11.0.4)"
      },
      {
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate"
      },
      {
        "X-PD-Event-Received": "1572013154"
      }
    ],
    "body": ""
  }
}
```

Above data needs to be parsed to look like the following:

```
description: "Interface is down for a viptela router"
cmdb_ci: "myrtr1"
Error URL: https://GINC.netspyglass.com/emb_graph.html?update=true&networkId=1&intervalHr=24&width=500&height=300&vars=ifOperStatus.9853.2
```

I tried the following:

```js
var body = PD.inputRequest.rawBody;
var cef_event = {
  event_type: PD.Trigger,
  description: body.details.payload.summary,
  cmdb_ci: body.details.payload.cmdb_ci,
  event_action: PD.Trigger,
  details: body.details
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error executing transform: TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined

Comment: I tried the following : var body = PD.inputRequest.rawBody;

var cef_event = {
 event_type: PD.Trigger,
   description: body.details.payload.summary,
 cmdb_ci: body.details.payload.cmdb_ci,
 event_action: PD.Trigger,
   details: body.details
}

Comment: I get the following error:Error executing transform: TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined

Comment: I am very very new to this scripting and I need some assitance from an expert at the earliest.

Comment: Hi Gopi, and welcome to SO!  You should generally edit your question instead of adding additional information in comments, as it makes it easier for readers to see the entire context at once.   I've proposed an edit that does this with your existing comments.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `rawBody` member of your JSON is a string, not an object, so you would need to do something like:

`var body = JSON.parse(PD.inputRequest.rawBody);`

Before you access its members.

Currently you are just assigning the string itself to `body`.

Moreover, once parsed, the keys in the JSON object related to payload aren't actually sub-objects, the keys are literally strings like `payload.summary`, so to access *those* you should do:

`body.details['payload.summary']`

Putting it all together, the code you supplied should be more like this (though it doesn't provide the output you listed, I presume there's more going on beyond the code you provided):

```js
var body = JSON.parse(PD.inputRequest.rawBody);
var cef_event = {
  event_type: PD.Trigger,
  description: body.details['payload.summary'],
  cmdb_ci: body.details['payload.cmdb_ci'],
  event_action: PD.Trigger,
  details: body.details
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
  description: "NetSpy Integration",
  event_type: "trigger",
  service_key: "34a9a87f27f6173f",
  details: {
    uri: {
      slashes: true,
      search: "",
      query: {},
      protocol: "http:",
      port: null,
      pathname: "/integration/34a9a87f27f6173f /enqueue",
      path: "/integration/34a9a87f27f6173f /enqueue",
      href: "http://events.pagerduty.com/integration/34a9a87f27f6173f/enqueue",
      hostname: "events.pagerduty.com",
      host: "events.pagerduty.com",
      hash: null,
      auth: null
    },
    rawBody: '{"client_url":"http://GINC-prod-nsg-mon-5:9100/","service_key":"34a9a87f27f6173f ","event_type":"trigger","description":"Interface is down for a viptela router","client":"NetSpyGlassTest","details":{"client":"NSG","client_url":"https://GINC.netspyglass.com/","component":"ge0/1","dedup_key":"$dedupKey","device":"myrtr1","event_action":"trigger","payload.class":"deploy","payload.cmdb_ci":"myrtr1","payload.component":"postgres","payload.custom_details.abc":"123","payload.custom_details.def":"Hi, its Nikita","payload.group":"prod-datapipe","payload.severity":"{}","payload.source":"https://GINC.netspyglass.com/","payload.summary":"Interface is down for a router","payload.timestamp":"","routing_key":"34a9a87f27f6173f ","value":"2.0"},"incident_key":"ViptelaRouterInterfaceDown.9853.2","contexts":[{"href":"http://GINC-prod-nsg-mon-5:9100/","type":"link"},{"src":"https://GINC.netspyglass.com/emb_graph.html?update=true&networkId=1&intervalHr=24&width=500&height=300&vars=ifOperStatus.9853.2","type":"image"}]}',
    method: "POST",
    headers: [{
        "X-Real-IP": "10.16.121.254"
      },
      {
        "X-Forwarded-For": "10.16.121.254"
      },
      {
        Host: "events.pagerduty.com"
      },
      {
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
      },
      {
        Connection: "close"
      },
      {
        "Content-Length": "1054"
      },
      {
        "User-Agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/11.0.4)"
      },
      {
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate"
      },
      {
        "X-PD-Event-Received": "1572013154"
      }
    ],
    body: ""
  }
};
data = JSON.parse(data.details.rawBody);
console.log(data.details["payload.class"]);
```